# Is it possible to lock an overloaded bracket operator?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Lets say I have

```
class a {
    public bool this[int index] { ... }
}
```

How do I `lock()` this operator? So that if anybody tries to call `aInst[4]`, for example, it blocks until the `lock()` block finishes execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the question is - the code you posted is just a indexer property. In the body of that property you can lock an object the same as from within any other property or method.

```
class a
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    public bool this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return ...;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                ... = value
            }
        }
    }

    public string AMethod()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return ...;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK yeah for some reason I was under the impression you could lock a function from being called, but it seems like this isn't actually the case. This is exactly what I'm looking for though, thank you.

Comment: Slight terminology improvement: You can't lock _properties_, you lock _objects_.